# Create NSManagedObject Subclass from Core Data Data Model in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

I've got two entities in a Core Data Data Model. There is a one to many relationship between them. When I navigate to *Editor* --> *Create NSManagedObject Subclass...*, my models are generated but I do not get strongly typed method signatures like `- (void)addPhotosObject:(NSManagedObject *)value;` on the many side of the relationship.

According to what I've read, in Xcode 5 at least, this is because the class on the one side of the relationship was created first so the class on the many side of the relationship does not yet exist. The suggestions I see say to to simply *Create NSManagedObject Subclass...* again and the method should generate methods with strongly typed classes but the method signatures are not changing to strongly type.

Is there a trick to getting strongly typed method signatures?

Comment: What exactly is a strongly typed method signature?

Comment: @Mundi Instead of declaring a method which takes the generic class `NSManagedObject`, it would ideally take my specific class type. In this example (from CS193P), I've got a `Photographer` class which has an `NSSet` of `Photo`. Ideally the method signature looks like `- (void)addPhotosObject:(Photo *)value;` as opposed to the signature you see in the question which uses `NSManagedObject`. Make sense?

Comment: OK, I understand. "Strongly typed" actually means something different. What you meant is usually called a `NSManagedObject` subclass.

Comment: I realize strongly typed is typically used when referring to a language and that Photo is indeed a subclass of `NSManagedObject` but thought that this was a good way to explain my problem. Admittedly, I found this question challenging to communicate. Do you have a suggestion for how you would have written this question @Mundi? Maybe I can update the question to make it a little more clear and learn something form your approach at the same time. cheers

Comment: Just not using "strongly typed" would have made it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

After deleting the `NSManagedObject` subclasses that were initially created by *Create NSManagedObject Subclass...* and simply re-generating them by selecting *Create NSManagedObject Subclass...* again, the method signatures ended up strongly typed which gave me a `Photo` as a parameter like this `- (void)addPhotosObject:(Photo *)value;` instead of an `NSManagedObject`.